# Castle Windsor : Configure a generic service and provide a non-generic implementation fails

Tags: c#, generics, castle-windsor

Using Castle Windsor, I want to configure a generic service with a type parameter; and have it implemented by a known concrete type that implements the service with a specific type as the generic parameter. Expressed as a unit test, I would like to get the following to work:

```
[TestClass]
public class WindsorTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void ResolveGenericEntity_Test()
    {
        WindsorContainer container = ConfigureContainer();
        IEntity<string> entity = container.Resolve<IEntity<string>>();
        Assert.IsNotNull(entity);
    }

    private WindsorContainer ConfigureContainer()
    {
        WindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.AddComponent("entity", typeof(IEntity<>), typeof(ConcreteEntity));
        return container;
    }
}

public interface IEntity<T> { }

public class ConcreteEntity : IEntity<string> {}
```

This test fails with the following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException:
>   WindsorGenericsTest.ConcreteEntity is
>   not a GenericTypeDefinition.
>   MakeGenericType may only be called on
>   a type for which
>   Type.IsGenericTypeDefinition is true.

Now, I have found a [post here](http://forum.castleproject.org/viewtopic.php?t=4085) describing the same problem. The poster describes how this can be resolved by changing the DefaultGenericHandler.ResolveCore method. However, I don't feel like changing the Castle code itself and running on a custom build.

Does anyone know how I can resolve this problem without modifying the Castle Windsor source code ? I am happy to implement a facility to support this, if that is what is needed.

Comment: The post you link to is wrong and it proposes a workaround, not a fix. Windsor is right, your registration is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will it work if you change the line in ConfigureContainer to this?

```
container.AddComponent("entity", typeof(IEntity<string>), typeof(ConcreteEntity));
```

Comment: Yes that works, but it is not what I need (the concrete usage is in a rather complicated graph of injected objects, my code sample is the shortest possible that reproduces the problem).

Comment: So what do you need? This answer is just the right solution to your problem from the question - your `ConcreteEntity` implements `IEntity<string>` not `IEntity<>` so you should register it as such